# Should the Register-AzureRmAutomationDscNode cmdlet function identically to the Azure portal functionality?

Tags: azure, azure-automation

We are seeing an issue with `Register-AzureRmAutomationDscNode` and are wondering if it is not working as expected or if our understanding of what it is supposed to do is incorrect.

When we onboard an Azure VM as an Azure Automation DSC node via the portal, everything works as expected. The VM is onboarded and the configuration is applied.

When we attempt to do the same via `Register-AzureRmAutomationDscNode`, the cmdlet appears to succeed, but the VM never appears as a DSC node in the portal or via the `Get-AzureRmAutomationDscNode` command.

We have verified the parameters we are passing via the UI in the portal and via the cmdlet are identical. In both cases, we also see a successful deployment on the VM with identical input and outputs.

The output from the cmdlet is:

```
DeploymentName          : 20170825085614
ResourceGroupName       : 36ddce91
ProvisioningState       : Succeeded
Timestamp               : 8/25/2017 2:57:17 PM
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            :
                          Uri            : https://eus2oaasibizamarketprod1.blob.core.windows.net/automationdscpreview/azuredeployV2.json
                          ContentVersion : 1.0.0.0

Parameters              :
                          Name             Type                       Value
                          ===============  =========================  ==========
                          vmName           String                     Windows-VM
                          location         String                     East US
                          modulesUrl       String                     https://eus2oaasibizamarketprod1.blob.core.windows.net/automationdscpreview/RegistrationMetaConfigV2.zip
                          configurationFunction  String                     RegistrationMetaConfigV2.ps1\RegistrationMetaConfigV2
                          registrationKey  SecureString
                          registrationUrl  String                     https://eus2-agentservice-prod-1.azure-automation.net/accounts/8b6a1713-dc00-4ae1-a513-c582def16380
                          nodeConfigurationName  String                     RemoteManagement.36ddce91
                          configurationMode  String                     ApplyAndMonitor
                          configurationModeFrequencyMins  Int                        15
                          refreshFrequencyMins  Int                        30
                          rebootNodeIfNeeded  Bool                       True
                          actionAfterReboot  String                     ContinueConfiguration
                          allowModuleOverwrite  Bool                       True
                          timestamp        String                     8/25/2017 2:56:14 PM

Outputs                 :
DeploymentDebugLogLevel :
```

Is there an issue with `Register-AzureRmAutomationDscNode` or does onboarding a VM via the portal perform additional actions that are not covered by `Register-AzureRmAutomationDscNode`?

Comment: well, whats the input? it was working for me pretty straight forwardly...